# function for rotating matrix returns the input

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

I was trying to answer to the interview question from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdZlsG6P17w) as a programming exercise in Python and I decided to use the first method Nick explained but for some reason my function always returns a matrix identical to the input and I'm really struggling to find the error

The function I wrote is:

```
def swap(inp):
    for i in range(len(inp)-1):
        for j in range(len(inp[i])-1):
            temp = inp[i][j]
            inp[i][j] = inp[j][i]
            inp[j][i] = temp
    return inp
```

Comment: ```return [list(sorted(i,reverse=True)) for i in zip(*inp)]```?

Comment: @Sujay Neither looks like an explanation of their error nor like a working solution.

Comment: Please add all the information we need to your question. How is `inp` defined? How do you call your function? How should the result look like?

Comment: I didn't want the post to be too long since I already included the video that explains in depth the exercise I'm trying to solve and how the input and output of the function should be @Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to watch the whole video but i clicked around and saw that "Step 1" c++ Code that looks quite similar to yours. I'm assuming you're trying to replicate that.

First of all, not sure what you want with those -1. You would leave the last row and the last column as they are if you do that.
Second, you're starting your inner loop at j=0, but in video it starts at j=i.

Your function with these modifications:

```
def swap(inp):
for i in range(len(inp)):
    for j in range(i, len(inp[i])):
        temp = inp[i][j]
        inp[i][j] = inp[j][i]
        inp[j][i] = temp
return inp
```

If you only give one argument to `range`, it assumes starting at 0. If you give it two arguments, it's from first argument to second argument, in this case from `i` to `len(inp[i])`.

EDIT: By the way, here is a solution making use of numpy functions that achieves the same results. At a quick glance I think transposing the input (`inp.T`) corresponds to Step 1 and `np.flip(..., 1)` is the horizontal flip.

```
def swap_numpy_style(inp):
    return np.flip(inp.T, 1)
```

Comment: I put len(inp)-1 because the last index of the list is lower by one than the actual length of the list so I thought if I didn't do it j would become an index out of range.  Also I don't really see why j should start at i if every inner list goes from 0 to len(inp[i]-1) . The code you provided actually kinda works but it flips the matrix diagonally instead of rotating it, which was the goal I was trying to obtain. Thanks for your help I'm trying to understand more but I'm really struggling seeing what's wrong

Comment: "because the last index of the list is lower by one than the actual length of the list" - the range function takes care of that.

"but it flips the matrix diagonally instead of rotating it" - well, I fixed the part of the solution that your code was supposed to do: flip diagonally, as explained in the video. To achieve the rotation it needs to be flipped horizontally, as explained in the video and done in my numpy solution.

Comment: Oooh I see now. Thank you for your time